# submitForm error with javascript on a PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links, javascript

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=None,pdfstartview=FitH,pdfview=FitH,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

\begin{document}

\pushButton[\CA{POST}\A{\JS{
url = "http://debis.deu.edu.tr/DEUWeb//hdp.php";
donem = "243";
fakulte2 = "126";
hafta = "18/09/2017_24/09/2017";
hoca = "7_8";
SUBMIT = "TAMAM";
app.alert(donem + " "+ fakulte2 +" "+  hafta +" "+ hoca +" "+  SUBMIT);
this.submitForm(url, false);
}}]{myButton}{36bp}{12bp}
\end{document}
```

This code gives an error as follows:

[image].

Is it a mistake to ask here this question? Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: I won't run tests with an unknown script on an unknown url. You should make a php available for local tests. Beside this: the url looks wrong. Why do you have two slashes before the file name?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, url does not wrong. It is working. Whether one slash or not two slashes. I don't know but it is working.